# debugging a statement in a Makefile on OpenBSD

Tags: make, openbsd, debugging

It is not clear to me, where the error comes from, the Makefile code follows:

```sh
platform_id = $$( uname -s )

platform = $$( \
    case $(platform_id) in \
        Linux | FreeBSD | OpenBSD | NetBSD ) echo $(platform_id) ;; \
        * ) echo Unrecognized ;; \
    esac )
```

and the first target in the Makefile is:

```sh
check:
    echo $(platform); echo
```

On both Linux Mint 19.0, and FreeBSD 11.2, it works without problem, tested with both GNU `make`, and BSD `make`. I mean on both of those systems with `gmake`, and `bmake`.

I am new to OpenBSD 6.4, and being unable to find the cause of the error is frustrating.

The error message with the command follows:

```sh
echo $(  case $( uname -s ) in Linux | FreeBSD | OpenBSD | NetBSD ) echo $( uname -s ) ;; * ) echo Unrecognized ;;  esac ); echo
/bin/sh: syntax error: ';;' unexpected
*** Error 1 in /root (Makefile:47 'check')
```

As I don't have guest additions installed yet, I must have transcripted but checked twice, it should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a shell with a broken parser....

Background: parsing `$(command)` needs a recursive parser to work correctly.

Note that the complete expression `$(command)` needs to be in a single string and `command` can be really complex. To find the end of the command, modern shells recursively call the parser and let it stop at the first superfluous `)`. `mksh` and `bosh` then convert the binary syntax tree back into a command, while `ksh93` shuffles the characters read by the recrusive parser into a buffer.

POSIX (really ksh88) at some time believed that this would work with a simple string parser that just counts  `(` and `)` and added a requirement to add  `(` before the case labels.

Since your command is not OK with respect to what POSIX believes, you could retry with changing:

```
    Linux | FreeBSD | OpenBSD | NetBSD ) echo $(platform_id) ;; \
```

into:

```
    ( Linux | FreeBSD | OpenBSD | NetBSD ) echo $(platform_id) ;; \
```

and

```
* ) echo Unrecognized ;; \
```

into

```
( * ) echo Unrecognized ;; \
```

If your shell is using such a primitive counting parser, it should work with that change.

Comment: Upgrading OpenBSD's `sh` from PD Korn to 93 Korn has come up a number of times over the past couple of decades.

Comment: ksh93, mksh, bash and bosh would all work. PD ksh is known to be full of bugs.